# Idea for an UI application architecture

Tags: architecture, class-design, desktop-application

I'm writing my first desktop Java application in standalone SWT/JFace (I don't want to use RCP) ; but it's not a problem of language so don't focus on the technology I use.

Just to explain in few words what does the software, the main window have a tab folder, each tab item represent a file the user can edit. A file is represented by a structured viewer. The application have menus and toolbars. There is a context menu in the tab item.

My question is on the architecture of the application.
I don't know how to make a good design architecture so that the code is correctly organised.

Each actions (in menus, in context menus and in toolbar) could change the content of the selected tab item so I don't know what to do :

1- the tab item expose a lot of public method which are called by all the actions ? So the tab item will have a lot of functionalities :
example : the add new line menu action in the menu or the context menu just calls the addNewLine() method of the tab item ?

2- a class that acts as a controller, manages the tab folder and all the tab items and expose a lot of public methods.
example : the open File menu action call the openFile() method on the controller, the add new line action calls the controller that knows the active tab and add the line where it is needed.

3- each action is a concrete class and just call as little method as possible on the tab item to refresh the UI.
example : the open file menu action has the logic to open the "open file dialog", to read the file data and called something like addNewTab(ApplicationObject my object) directly on the UI components

4- ... ?

In your point of view, which one is the best practice ?
Do you know where I can find example / documentation on design for a desktop application like this ?

Thanks in advance,

Fluminis

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read how to design event base applications (could be Java, Android, Flash or VB.Net) and a concrete resource is the book [Growing Object-Oriented Software](http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com/). In that book, the authors explain how to build and test a Swing application, and the design they use is perfect (from my point of view, of course).